# cPanel stopped responding to curl requests

Tags: bash, curl, cpanel

I'm on a VPS and use a bash script to deploy websites to subdirectories inside on of my accounts. I've been using this script with no issues until today, randomly, cPanel decided to ignore curl.

In this script I automatically create a database and add a user to it, which is accomplished via curling cPanel with the appropriate information.

Here's what I was doing and previously was working flawlessly.

```
curl -k -v -G -d db=$db_name https://$cpanel_user:$cpanel_password@$cpanel_host:2083/frontend/x3/sql/addb.html
```

I isolated this line to a separate script to debug. Here's the kicker, the server simply doesn't respond. Curl just says `Trying X.X.X.X...` and then eventually the connection times out. Curl works for everything else so I know that's not it. Just for grins I tried wget and it can't establish a connection either.

I have [had] security tokens disabled in cPanel.

My question is what would cause the connection to fail? I'm stumped as this worked yesterday.

I don't mind investigating and debugging, but with no errors or anything I simply don't know where to look. I talked to my host and they said there hasn't been any firewall/security updates rolled out.

Suggestions on issues or where to look?

**Edit:** So if I run that curl command locally in OSX it fires up and creates the DB no problem. So for some reason the URL isn't responding to my own server (itself) o.O

**Edit 2**: It seems my server can't curl itself on that port I need (dunno why it would have stopped). For example if I curl my server IP or a domain on my server (from the server) it works. If I try to curl my ip:2083 it won't resolve.

How can I allow curl to work with port 2083?

Comment: Are you sure that thing isn't behind a proxy or something? That would have about this effect. Can you connect to localhost:2083?

Answer (score 0):

My firewall CSF just allow incomming TCP connexion on port 2083 to the server.  But the other one blocked the outgoing tcp connexion on port 2083.

So opening both port IN-OUT on both server solved the issue.